# Could having audio as stream 0 and video as stream 1 explain why my MPG will play on OSX QuickTime Player, but not Win10 Movies & TV?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

All I wanted was to trim a video file...

I used ffmpeg to trim a 30-minute video+audio file down to the 2min 40s I want.
My trimmed file plays fine on a Mac using QuickTime Player, but on my Win10 box with the default app (Movies & TV?), the audio plays fine, but the video is black.

I dug in with ffprobe.  It seems like the trimming process also flipped the order of the streams.  That is, the original file has video as stream 0 and audio as stream 1, but the trimmed file has audio as stream 0 and video as stream 1.  **Could this be the culprit?**  Is that ordering unusual enough that not all players may behave correctly with it?

Before trimming:

```
ffprobe -hide_banner myfile.mpg
[h264 @ 0000013931b562c0] Increasing reorder buffer to 2
[mpegts @ 0000013931b4fe00] PES packet size mismatch
[mpegts @ 0000013931b4fe00] Packet corrupt (stream = 1, dts = 8467425232).
[mpegts @ 0000013931b4fe00] Could not find codec parameters for stream 2 (Unknown: none ([151][0][0][0] / 0x0097)): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mpegts, from 'myfile.mpg':
  Duration: 00:30:00.63, start: 92282.982578, bitrate: 6249 kb/s
  Program 1
    Stream #0:0[0x1aab]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], Closed Captions, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 119.88 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1abf]: Audio: ac3 ([129][0][0][0] / 0x0081), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x1ac1]: Unknown: none ([151][0][0][0] / 0x0097)
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 2
```

After trimming:

```
ffprobe -hide_banner myfile.trimmed.mpg
[h264 @ 00000170c21c69c0] Increasing reorder buffer to 2
Input #0, mpeg, from 'myfile.trimmed.mpg':
  Duration: 00:02:41.09, start: 0.500000, bitrate: 6255 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x80]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s
    Stream #0:1[0x1e2]: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], Closed Captions, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 119.88 tbc
```

Comment: Show the command you used, and the complete log if possible (without the accursed `-hide_banner` as it hides important info).

Comment: `but the trimmed file has audio as stream 0 and video as stream 1. Could this be the culprit?` No.

Comment: You're right; the stream order was not the problem.  Rather, I can't legally have H264 video in a .mpg container.    Remuxing to a .mp4 file got Windows to play it.